# Array of char* in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

What I want my program to do is to read an input text from the user, tokenize that string with the whitespace being the delimiter and store each of the tokens int an array of char* which will then be returned.

here is a snippet of code that I am trying to make it work correctly:

```
typedef char* String;
String* split(char* cmd)
{
    char* param;
    char tmp[128];
    String* result = (String*) malloc(10*sizeof(String));
    memset(result,NULL,10);

    strcpy(tmp,cmd);

    param = strtok(tmp," ");

    int index = 0;
    while(param && index < sizeof(result) / sizeof(*result))
    {

        result[index] = (char*) malloc(strlen(param));
        strcpy(result[index],param);

        param = strtok(NULL," ");
        index++;
    }

}
```

Where cmd is the string that I am tokenizing and result is the array that will contain each token.

This snippet causes errors when trying to iterate through the returned result using a simple for loop (A segmentation fault arises)

```
String* splittedCmd = split(command);

int i;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(splittedCmd[i] != NULL)
        printf("%s\n",splittedCmd[i]);
}
```

Comment: Think about local variables and lifetime. Think about dynamic allocation, and why you don't have it. Think about using `strncpy` instead. Think about marking this as "homework". And think about switching to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong here.

First and most obvious, you are returning `result` which is an array (but decays to a pointer to an array) that is allocated on the stack in the function so it is reclaimed when the function returns. You need to dynamically allocate the array (and rely on the caller to `free` it):

```
String *result = malloc(10 * sizeof(String));
```

Also, your condition to stop the `while` loop:

```
if(index == sizeof(result))
```

Will let the loop go until `index` is `40` (if `char*` is 4 bytes on your platform) because `sizeof` returns the size of the operand in bytes, not array elements, so `sizeof(result)` is (again, platform dependent) 40. This is obviously beyond the bounds of the array.

If you were still using a local array instead of `malloc`, you could change that to

```
if (index == sizeof(result) / sizeof(*result))
```

However, you can't do that now because `result` is only a pointer instead of an array and `sizeof(result)` will always be the size of a pointer on your platform.

You can just remove that `if` completely and change the `while` condition to

```
while (param && index < 10)
```

Which makes sure that `param` is not `NULL` and also that `index` is less than 10. You should consider making a `#define` or a `const int` or something for the size of the array and use that instead of using a magic number.

You also need to change

```
memset(result,NULL,10);
```

to

```
memset(result,NULL, sizeof(String) * 10);
```

Because if you don't, `memset` is only setting the first 10 bytes of the memory pointed to be `result` to 0, instead of the whole thing, because it takes the number in bytes, not array elements.

Comment: I tried allocating memory and I still can't print the contents of `splittedCmd`

Comment: @user1162954 post your updated code. Don't forget that you also have to change your loop.

Comment: @user1162954 yes, you did `while(param && index < sizeof(result) / sizeof(*result))` which I had wrote before, but I made a mistake and that's wrong too. Read my answer for the update (tl;dr: the loop should be `while (result && index < 10)` because `sizeof` doesn't work the same on pointers as it does on arrays).

Comment: I see, but the program crashes even when param has one token

Comment: @user1162954 I see also that now in your program you removed `return result;`. You need to add that back in.

Comment: @user1162954 oh, I found the problem. `memset(result,NULL,10);` should be `memset(result,NULL, sizeof(String) * 10);` because `memset` takes the number in bytes. I changed that and tested the function and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint - why don't you try to use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)? It would simplify things greatly.

Comment: Someone else also didn't realise he's using it already I guess :)

Comment: Yeah, good catch on result being allocated on the stack. I was just about to edit my answer saying that when yours popped up.

Answer (score 0):

You should not return a pointer to local variable. After the function `split` return, the memory address of `result` may contain garbage, and therefore you refer to invalid pointer when you try to print it.